# $Ext$ preserves products

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an $Ab4$ category. Define $\mathrm{Ext}^{n}(-,-):\mathcal{A}^{op}\times\mathcal{A}\rightarrow Ab$ bifunctor using n-extensions. Consider $A$ an object of  $\mathcal{A}$. Does $\mathrm{Ext}^{n}(-,A)$ preserve products?

Comment: This looks a lot like homework, and anyways is not a research-level math question.

Comment: This is not a homework. 

Comment: It seems to me that this interesting question has been misunderstood so far. Let me rephrase it as follows: Assume we are in an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ satisfying (AB4). Define $\mathrm{Ext}^n(-,-) : \mathcal{A}^{op} \times \mathcal{A} \to \mathrm{Ab}$ not as a derived functor (which is not possible since we didn't assume that $\mathcal{A}$ has enough injectives or projectives), but rather via n-extensions (see e.g. Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor for a summary of this construction). Do we have $\mathrm{Ext}^n(\oplus_i A_i,A) \cong \prod_i \mathrm{Ext}^n(A_i,A)$?

Comment: Yes, it does.  I trust that this is not homework; still, it is a good excercise in Yoneda Ext, and a not very difficult one.  Just construct maps in both directions between the Ext from a direct sum and the product of the Exts; then check straightforwardly from the definition that both compositions are the idenitity maps (of sets).  Let me know if any further directions are needed.

Comment: You mention AB4, which is about infinite products/coproducts. Are you interested in finite products or infinite products?

Comment: @Positselski: what is the map $ \prod_i \mathrm{Ext}^n(A_i,A)\to \mathrm{Ext}^n(\oplus_i A_i,A) $?

Comment: Buschi: consider your collection of $(n+2)$-term exact sequences representing your Yoneda extension classes from $A_i$ to $A$. Take the direct sum of these. Since you are in an AB4 category, you get an exact sequence, which will therefore represent a Yoneda extension class from $\bigoplus_i A_i$ to $\bigoplus_i A$. Compose it with the natural morphism $\bigoplus_i A \to A$ (corresponding to the collection of idenitity maps $A\to A$). Now you have the desired Yoneda extension class from $\bigoplus_i A_i$ to $A$. 

Comment: @Positselski: the Yoneda resolution is from $\bigoplus_i A$ to $\bigoplus_i A_i$, and composing with the morfisms $\Delta: A\to \bigoplus_i A$ dont get in general a exat sequence.



Comment: A nice exposition of $Ext^n(A, C)$ in general abelian categories is in BArry Mitchell "Theory of categories".

Comment: Buschi: excuse me please, but are you sure that you remember how does one compose Yoneda Ext elements with morphisms in the abelian category?  If not, you may want to consult your own reference.

Comment: sorry, I misinterpreted the term "compose".
